# Add two select to one select

Tags: javascript, select

I want javascript
Click the "Add" button
From the first "Select"
And the second "Select"
Add "Select" to the third one
[Link](https://freeimages-hd.com/images/2017/06/27/Untitled.png)

Thanks

Comment: No one to answer?

Comment: I guess we need some code, or at least a try.

Comment: I need the code
I do not know myself
I want your help

Comment: Then your on the wrong website. There is plenty of websites where you can find developers that will do your work for some dollars, but here we are helping people, not doing there work for free. Hope you understand the difference.

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE].  It is expected that you have at least tried to do something yourself and then if you get stuck, come to us with a specific coding problem.  At the moment your question is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site as it is too broad

Comment: پیش از این که  سوالی رو مطرح کنین پیشنهاد میکنم قوانین سوالات رو مطالعه کنید تا اینگونه نمره منفی نگیرید و عکس از خارج از مجموعه داخل سوال نگذارید لذا شاید بعد ها سوال دیگران هم باشه و عکس های خارجی از بین رفته باشند. با این حال پاسخ سوالتون رو دادم

Answer (score -1):

The sample:

HTML:

```
   <div >
        <select name="color" id="sel1">
            <option value="red"> red </option>
            <option value="blue"> blue </option>
            <option value="pink"> pink </option>
            <option value="lime"> lime </option>

        </select>

        <select name="other" id="sel2">
            <option value="value"> text </option>
            <option value="value1"> text1 </option>
            <option value="value2"> text2 </option>
            <option value="value3"> text3 </option>

        </select>

        <button id="click-me">Add ro thrid</button>
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <select name="result" id="result" multiple="" style="height:170px;width: 300px">

        </select>
    </div>
```

Jquery code:

```
        $(function () {
            $("#click-me").click(function () {
                var txt = $("#sel1").val() + '-' + $("#sel2").val();
                $("#result").append("<option value='" + txt + "' >" + txt + '</option>');
            });
        });
```

Sample in [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cyh07ew/)